# Object required error despite successful operation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to build many different PowerPoint slides made up of elements from a set of 12 (I called them 'stencils') - for each slide only the elements' order and the text within in the elements changes.

Goal:
Go through lines in Excel. Each line represents one usage of a 'stencil'. In column 5 it says what 'stencil' to use (from an ID) and then the other columns contain the texts for the fields.
All the stencils are on the last slide of the presentation from where I copy the relevant one, paste it and fill it with text.

One of those stencils is a textbox nothing more (a headline). All the others are groups of shapes.

When I try to run this code it tells me 424 "Object required" for that line

```
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wks.Range(line, CLMN).Text
```

...but after it ran successfully. The header is on the slide and the text is correct.

How can it require an object after the fact?

Full Sub:

```
Sub AddShape(typ As Integer, state As Integer, currentSld As Slide, height As Long, line As Integer)

    'Set the constants (although not implemented as Const)
    Dim CLMN As Integer
    CLMN = 5
    Dim stencils As Shapes
    Dim stencilSlide As Integer
    stencilSlide = CInt(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    Set stencils = ActivePresentation.Slides(stencilSlide).Shapes

    Dim HEADER As Shape
    Set HEADER = stencils("header")

    Dim ALPHANUMERICAL As Shape
    Set ALPHANUMERICAL = stencils("alphanumerical")

    Dim BIRTHDATE As Shape
    Set BIRTHDATE = stencils("birthdate")

    Dim TOGGLE As Shape
    Set TOGGLE = stencils("toggle")

    Dim DROPDOWN As Shape
    Set DROPDOWN = stencils("dropdown")

    Dim NUMERICAL As Shape
    Set NUMERICAL = stencils("numerical")

    Select Case typ
    Case 1
        ALPHANUMERICAL.Copy
    Case 2
        NUMERICAL.Copy
    Case 4
        DROPDOWN.Copy
    Case 5
        TOGGLE.Copy
    Case 9
        BIRTHDATE.Copy
    End Select

    If typ = 10 Then
        HEADER.Copy
        With currentSld.Shapes.Paste
            .Top = height
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wks.Range(line, CLMN).Text
        End With
    Else
        With currentSld.Shapes.Paste
            .Top = height
            For x = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
                If .GroupItems(x).Name = "label" Then
                    With .GroupItems(x)
                        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wks.Range(line, CLMN).Text
                    End With
                Else
                    With .GroupItems(x)
                        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wks.Range(line, CLMN + CInt(.GroupItems(x).Name)).Text
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Are `line` and `CLMN` `Long` variables, representing `Row` and `Column`?

Comment: yes, but Integers

Comment: Using `Integer` for rows is wrong (for big/possible rows number). Its maximum value is 32767 (16-bit (2-byte) numbers) and maximum rows nunber, starting with Excel 2010 is much bigger. It wold be a good habit to **always** use `Long` type... VBA keeps Integer only for compatibility with old versions.

Comment: "MSDN: In recent versions, however, VBA converts all integer values to type Long, even if they're declared as type Integer." " in fact, Long variables may be slightly faster because VBA does not have to convert them." If you have doubts, please check [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164506(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using of `wks.Cells(line, CLMN).Value` instead of `wks.Range(line, CLMN).Text`.

I suppose that `line` and `CLMN` are Long variables, representing `Row` and `Column`.

But, if `line` is a `String` representing the literal part of an address (like "A", "B", "AB") you must use `wks.Range(line & CLMN).Value`

Comment: Looking at the code, they are both Integer so yes will need to use Cells instead of Range.

Comment: Using `Integer` for rows is not the best choice (for big/possible rows number). Its maximum value is 32767 (16-bit (2-byte) numbers). It wold be a good habit to always use Long type... VBA keeps Integer only for compatibility with old versions.

Comment: @ACCtionMan: "MSDN: In recent versions, however, VBA converts all integer values to type Long, even if they're declared as type Integer." " in fact, Long variables may be slightly faster because VBA does not have to convert them." If you have doubts, please check [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164506(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).